# Error: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. when try to access to Postgres Db

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I have an application with.Net **6** and **SQL Server**. Now I want to change my database to **Postgres** for some reason. With the database-first approach, I have successfully created a database schema. Everything went smoothly, but my application keeps getting the following error whenever it tries to access the database. There is no error related to Db connection string

**UPDATE**

I created a new project and began replicating my previous project step by step. Surprisingly, it worked without any issues or code breaks. However, I couldn't pinpoint the exact reason why my previous project was not functioning correctly with the same code.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
  Source=Npgsql
  StackTrace:
   at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.<ExecuteWithTimeout>d__4`1.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.<WithCancellation>d__1`1.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.<WithTimeout>d__0`1.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ConnectAsync>d__210.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<RawOpen>d__208.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<<Open>g__OpenCore|203_1>d.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>d__203.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<OpenNewConnector>d__31.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenInternalAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenInternalAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.<OpenAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<InitializeReaderAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNextAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__15`1.MoveNext()
   at Crogics.ERP.Web.Models.InitialDataSeeder.<<AddAdministrator>b__6_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\rojics\CrogicsERPLite\Source\Crogics.ERP.Web\Models\InitialDataSeeder.cs:line 47
   at Crogics.ERP.Web.Models.InitialDataSeeder.AddAdministrator() in C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\rojics\CrogicsERPLite\Source\Crogics.ERP.Web\Models\InitialDataSeeder.cs:line 43
   at Crogics.ERP.Web.Models.InitialDataSeeder.Initialize() in C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\rojics\CrogicsERPLite\Source\Crogics.ERP.Web\Models\InitialDataSeeder.cs:line 36
   at Crogics.ERP.Web.Extensions.ApplicationBuilderExtensions.Initialize(IApplicationBuilder app) in C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\rojics\CrogicsERPLite\Source\Crogics.ERP.Web\Extensions\ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs:line 163
   at Crogics.ERP.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\rojics\CrogicsERPLite\Source\Crogics.ERP.Web\Startup.cs:line 76
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
```

## InitialDataSeeder.cs

```
using Crogics.ERP.Data;
using Crogics.ERP.Domain.Identity;
using Crogics.ERP.Shared.Constants;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace Crogics.ERP.Web.Models
{
    public interface IInitialDataSeeder
    {
        void Initialize();
    }

    public class InitialDataSeeder : IInitialDataSeeder
    {
        private readonly ILogger<InitialDataSeeder> _logger;
        private readonly CrogicsERPContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

        public InitialDataSeeder(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager,
            CrogicsERPContext db,
            ILogger<InitialDataSeeder> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _db = db;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            AddAdministrator();
            _db.SaveChanges();
            AddRoles();
        }

        private void AddAdministrator()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                //SupperAdmin
                var SupperAdminRole = new ApplicationRole(Roles.SuperAdmin);

//InitialDataSeeder.cs:line 47 This is the point where my db get hitted first time
                var SupperAdminRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.SuperAdmin);
                if (SupperAdminRoleInDb == null)
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(SupperAdminRole);
                    SupperAdminRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.SuperAdmin);
                    //adding role permissions
                    this.AddRolePermissions(SupperAdminRoleInDb.Id, typeof(Permissions));
                }
                //Check if User Exists
                var superUser = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    FirstName = "first",
                    LastName = "second",
                    Email = "some.ran@gmail.com",
                    UserName = "some.ran@gmail.com",
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                    InsertedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    IsActive = true
                };
                var superUserInDb = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(superUser.Email);
                if (superUserInDb == null)
                {
                    await _userManager.CreateAsync(superUser, Defaults.DefaultPassword);
                    var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(superUser, Roles.SuperAdmin);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        superUserInDb = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(superUser.Email);
                        _logger.LogInformation("Seeded Default SuperAdmin User.");


                        //Adding user permisssions
                        var roles = await _db.Roles.Include(r => r.RoleModules).ThenInclude(rp => rp.RoleModulePermissions).Where(r => r.Name == Roles.SuperAdmin).ToListAsync();
                        if(roles.Any())
                        {
                            var userClaims = new List<Claim>();
                            foreach (var role in roles)
                            {
                                foreach (var roleModule in role.RoleModules)
                                {
                                    foreach (var rolePermission in roleModule.RoleModulePermissions)
                                    {
                                        var claim = new Claim("Permissions." + roleModule.ModuleName, rolePermission.PermissionValue!);
                                        userClaims.Add(claim);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(userClaims.Any())
                            {
                                await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(superUserInDb, userClaims);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                        {
                            _logger.LogError(error.Description);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private void AddRoles()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                //SupperAdmin
                var SupperAdminRole = new ApplicationRole(Roles.SuperAdmin);
                var SupperAdminRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.SuperAdmin);
                if (SupperAdminRoleInDb == null)
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(SupperAdminRole);
                    SupperAdminRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.SuperAdmin);
                    //adding role permissions
                    this.AddRolePermissions(SupperAdminRoleInDb.Id, typeof(Permissions));
                }
                else
                {
                    AddRolePermissionsIfNotExists(SupperAdminRoleInDb.Id, typeof(Permissions));
                }

                //Admin
                var AdminRole = new ApplicationRole(Roles.Admin);
                var AdminRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.Admin);
                if (AdminRoleInDb == null)
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(AdminRole);
                    AdminRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.Admin);
                    //adding role permissions
                    this.AddRolePermissions(AdminRoleInDb.Id, typeof(Permissions));
                }
                else
                {
                    AddRolePermissionsIfNotExists(AdminRoleInDb.Id, typeof(Permissions));
                }

                //Manager
                var ManagerRole = new ApplicationRole(Roles.Manager);
                var ManagerRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.Manager);
                if (ManagerRoleInDb == null)
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(ManagerRole);
                    ManagerRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.Manager);
                    //adding role permissions
                    this.AddRolePermissions(ManagerRoleInDb.Id, typeof(ManagerPermissions));
                }
                else
                {
                    AddRolePermissionsIfNotExists(ManagerRoleInDb.Id, typeof(ManagerPermissions));
                }

                //Supervisor
                var SupervisorRole = new ApplicationRole(Roles.Supervisor);
                var SupervisorRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.Supervisor);
                if (SupervisorRoleInDb == null)
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(SupervisorRole);
                    SupervisorRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.Manager);
                    //adding role permissions
                    this.AddRolePermissions(SupervisorRoleInDb.Id, typeof(SupervisorPermissions));
                }
                else
                {
                    AddRolePermissionsIfNotExists(SupervisorRoleInDb.Id, typeof(SupervisorPermissions));
                }

                //employee
                var employeeRole = new ApplicationRole(Roles.Employee);
                var employeeRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.Employee);
                if (employeeRoleInDb == null)
                {
                    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(employeeRole);
                    employeeRoleInDb = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(Roles.Employee);
                    //adding role permissions
                    this.AddRolePermissions(employeeRoleInDb.Id, typeof(EmployeePermissions));
                }
                else
                {
                    AddRolePermissionsIfNotExists(employeeRoleInDb.Id, typeof(EmployeePermissions));
                }
            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        }
        private void AddRolePermissionsIfNotExists(int roleId, Type type)
        {
            var roles = _db.Roles.Include(r => r.RoleModules).ThenInclude(rp => rp.RoleModulePermissions).Where(r => r.Id == roleId).ToList();
            var role = roles.FirstOrDefault();
            if (role != null)
            {
                var roleModules = role?.RoleModules;
                if (roleModules != null)
                {
                    if (roleModules.Count == 0)
                    {
                        this.AddRolePermissions(roleId, type);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.AddRolePermissions(roleId, type);
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddRolePermissions(int roleId, Type type)
        {
            using (var transaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var permissionType in type.GetNestedTypes())
                    {
                        var moduleName = permissionType.Name;
                        var roleModule = new RoleModule() { ModuleName = moduleName, RoleId = roleId };
                        _db.RoleModules.Add(roleModule);
                        _db.SaveChanges();
                        foreach (var prop in permissionType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
                        {
                            var modulePermission = prop.GetValue(null);
                            if (modulePermission is not null)
                            {
                                var roleModulePermission = new RoleModulePermission() { RoleModuleId = roleModule.Id, PermissionValue = modulePermission.ToString() };
                                _db.RoleModulePermissions.Add(roleModulePermission);
                                _db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share more details about `InitialDataSeeder.cs:line 47`, and please kindly check the connectionstring is correct or not, tks~

Comment: Thanks, for your response, I have updated the question.

Comment: SocketException means there is some network issue when connecting the Postgres Db. You can try to test it via the code, like： https://codeshare.io/MNqv3y